# I don't want to include external jar in my maven war

Tags: maven, war

I don't want to include external jars when I build a war.What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not sure about why are you thinking to exclude the jar files, but yes you can do that if you are using `maven-war-plugin`

This will work out

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

This a whole bunch of configuration plugin that excludes all `.jar` files.

[This](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html) source explains about that and even regex patterns that can be used.